# set some class to html with javascript after check with if

Tags: jquery, ajax, class, append, thymeleaf

I have notification in Spring Boot app that come from DB with AJAX and parse to html div. I need set some of them style to show witch of them Unread. So I have boolean  property "seen". I think check if seen is false to add some class to generated table.

in Thymeleaf I did somethink like that:

```
<div th:classappend="${com.getUserId() == order.getUserId()} ? 'comment-name by-author' : 'comment-name'">


   

 $.map(notifications, function (not) {
            $("#not1").append(
                "<table > <tr></tr> <tr>"
                + "<td class='notTable'> <img src="+not.fromUserAvatar+" class=\"avatarNot\">"+ "</td>"
                + "<td class='notTable timeago '> <a  onClick=\"reply_click("+not.id+")\" class='fontSize timeago' href="+not.url+"> <span class='fontSize'>"
                + not.fromUserName +' '+ not.message + "</span> "              +'<br>'
                + "<abbr class=\"timeago\">" + jQuery.timeago(not.createDate) + "</abbr>" + "</a> </td>"
                + "</tr>  </table>"
            );
            if(datan.lastNotId < not.id) { // count last added notification id
                datan.lastNotId = not.id;
            }
            if(!not.seen) {
                datan.notCount ++; //count unread notification
            }
        });
        $('#noti_Counter').text(datan.notCount); //Add notification count
    },
```

Comment: Please show us the generated HTML for the notification that you want to style and your CSS styles (or information on what the classes should be) so that we can help.

Comment: I  want add class to style notification us unread by checking if seen is false.

Comment: you need to add that on `tr` ?

Comment: @Swati yes on <tr>

Comment: You can use `var classes="";  if(!not.seen) { classes="unread"; }else{classes="read";}` and then while appending do like this i.e : `$("#not1").append( "<table > <tr></tr> <tr class="+classes+">..`

Comment: Thanks! This is working!